# Django- insert image in password-reset email

Tags: django, python-3.x, image

I am implementing Django inbuilt functionality of the password reset.
I have overridden the standard email template but I don't know how to include an image in that email template.
I have tried the static thing but its giving me a plain text in the email.

**password_reset_email.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}Hey, You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}


<img src="{% static 'img/IMG_2095.jpg' %}" alt="My image">


{% endautoescape %}
```

**Email which i received**
[image: The email i am receiving]

Comment: can you show how you are using the corresponding view and forms?

Answer (score 0):

remove this: {%

```
incorrect: {% <img src="{% static 'img/IMG_2095.jpg' %}" alt="My image">

correct:    <img src="{% static 'img/IMG_2095.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

Comment: still it's not working
It looks like image has to been included in some tags

Comment: did you do this ```html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_html_email.html'```?